# ReactJS | When element reach top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a ReactJS version of this, when my component reaches top of page. The jQuery way is very simple, I would like it to stay that simple..

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > element.offset().top) {

    }
});
```

Comment: your component needs to listen to the scroll event. on each event check the position of the scroll and your component. give it a try. try looking up applying scroll event to react component.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I posted here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134985/reactjs-how-can-access-property-of-scrollbox-horizontal-offset/49135307?noredirect=1#comment85275725_49135307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the ref of your element and do your usual logic.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
}

// scroll event handler
handleScroll() {
  if(this.elem && this.elem.offsetTop > document.body.scrollTop) {
    // do your stuff
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

render() {
  return(
    <div className='wrapper' ref={elem => {this.elem = elem}}>
      // this will bind your component's reference so you can
      // use it in your event handler
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

See the example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/p0jo37147

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined

Comment: @PontusKihlberg I have edited my answer and added example codesandbox link as well. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

```
const ScrollToTop = () => {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0)
 return null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Steps to follow:
1. Hook onScroll event listener to document by:

`window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onHandleScrollEvent);`

this.onHandleScrollEvent will be your handler function it is analogous to the `$(window).on('scroll',()=>{})` callback function.

**Note:**
If your project has jquery included in it you can directly use the code in componentDidMount:

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
 onScrollFunction = function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > element.offset().top) {
       // do not do DOM manipulation using Jquery here.
    }
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  $(window).on('scroll',this.onScrollFunction);
 }
 render(){
   return(null)
 }
}
```

Refer to [Reactjs: How can access property of scrollbox (horizontal offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134985/reactjs-how-can-access-property-of-scrollbox-horizontal-offset/49135307?noredirect=1#comment85275725_49135307) for detailed implementation.

Comment: And if I don't want to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Agreed this is not the most efficient implementation.